# How to map array into another array of object

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

Json 1

```
{
  "ordering_data": [
    {
      "order": 0,
      "section_menu_id": 3
    },
    {
      "order": 1,
      "section_menu_id": 1
    },
    {
      "order": 2,
      "section_menu_id": 6
    },
  ]
}
```

Json 2

```
[
  3,
  7,
  4,
]
```

Expected result

```
{
  "ordering_data": [
    {
      "order": 3,
      "section_menu_id": 3
    },
    {
      "order": 7,
      "section_menu_id": 1
    },
    {
      "order": 4,
      "section_menu_id": 6
    },
  ]
}
```

I got 2 json files. can someone tell me how to change the data structure to expected result .I have tried map but it kinda confused for me. Need some help .Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us how you have tried to use map. Maybe it will be easier for us to explain what you are doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to accomplish this.

On `Array.map`, through the reference, the second param represents the current index of the array so based on that value, you can assign `second array value` to `order` key by `index`.

```js
const input1 = {
  "ordering_data": [
    {
      "order": 0,
      "section_menu_id": 3
    },
    {
      "order": 1,
      "section_menu_id": 1
    },
    {
      "order": 2,
      "section_menu_id": 6
    },
  ]
};

const input2 = [
  3,
  7,
  4,
];

const updatedOrderingData = input1.ordering_data.map((item, index) => ({
  ...item,
  order: input2[index]
}));
const result = {
  ordering_data: updatedOrderingData
};
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like the below code snippet.

This assumes that both objects are of equal length, and we are modifying the original object.

First, loop the array, and replace the order in the original object with the numbers in the array.

Make it an exercise to create a new object instead of modifying the original `obj1`

```js
var obj1 = {
  "ordering_data": [
    {
      "order": 0,
      "section_menu_id": 3
    },
    {
      "order": 1,
      "section_menu_id": 1
    },
    {
      "order": 2,
      "section_menu_id": 6
    },
  ]
};

var myArray = [
  3,
  7,
  4,
];

for(var i = 0; i<myArray.length; i++){
  obj1.ordering_data[i].order = myArray[i];
}
console.log(obj1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

```
    j1 = {
  "ordering_data": [
    {
      "order": 0,
      "section_menu_id": 3
    },
    {
      "order": 1,
      "section_menu_id": 1
    },
    {
      "order": 2,
      "section_menu_id": 6
    },
  ]
};

j2 = [
  3,
  7,
  4,
]

for(i=0; i<j1.ordering_data.length; i++ ){
  j1.ordering_data[i].order = j2[i]
}
```